# The errors cannot read properties of unchecked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react. I have this problems. App.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'checked')
My App.js Code

```
import dataMovielist from '../src/data/data.json';
import Members from './Members';
import AddMember from './AddMember';
import {useState} from 'react';

function App() {
  
  const [ischecked, setischecked] = useState(false);
  const [itemId, setitemid] = useState("");

  function checkEvent(event,itemid){
    if(event.target.checked===true){
      setischecked(true);
    };
    setitemid(itemid); 
  }
  
  const [datalist, setdatalist] = useState(dataMovielist);

  const onSubmitHandler = ((newHobbies)=>{
    setdatalist((oldHobbies)=>[newHobbies,...oldHobbies])
  })  
  
  const ondeleteHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("hi")
    console.log(ischecked);
    console.log(itemId)
    let copy = [...datalist];
    copy=copy.filter((item,index) => itemId!==index)
   
    setdatalist(copy);
}; 

  return (
    
    <div className="App">
       <AddMember onSubmitHandler = {onSubmitHandler} ondeleteHandler = {ondeleteHandler} />
       <Members data={datalist}  onChangeHandler={checkEvent} />   
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My AddMember.js code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../src/css/addMember.css";

const AddMember = ({onSubmitHandler, ondeleteHandler}) => {
  const [idmovie,setidmovie] = useState("");
  const [nameofmovie, setnameofmovie] = useState("");
  const [moviepic, setmoviepic] = useState("");
  const [leadActor, setleadActor] = useState("");
  const [rating, setRating] = useState("");
  
  function onChangeId(event){
    setidmovie(event.target.value);
  }

  function onChangeName(event) {
     setnameofmovie(event.target.value);
  }

  function onChangeImage(event) {
    setmoviepic(event.target.value);
  }

  function onChangeActor(event) {
    setleadActor(event.target.value.split(","));
  }

  function onChangeRating(event) {
    setRating(event.target.value);
  }

  const transferValue = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const val = {
      id : idmovie,
      name: nameofmovie,
      "picture of image": moviepic,
      "lead actor": leadActor,
      rating: rating,
    };
    onSubmitHandler(val);
    clearState();
  };

  const clearState = () => {
    setidmovie("");
    setnameofmovie("");
    setmoviepic("");
    setleadActor("");
    setRating("");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div id="topFormLayerOne">
        <form>
          <div id="secondFormLayerTwo">
            <label id="labelTwo">Please key in the Id</label>
            <input
              id="inputThree"
              type="text"
              maxLength="10"
              onChange={onChangeId}
              placeholder="Please key in the Id"
            ></input>
            <label id="labelFour">Movie Names</label>
            <input
              onChange={onChangeName}
              id="inputFour"
              type="text"
              maxLength="100"
              placeholder="Movies Names"
              name="moviesName"
            ></input>
            <label id="labelFive">Picture of Movies</label>
            <input
              onChange={onChangeImage}
              id="inputFive"
              type="file"
              maxLength="100"
              placeholder="Name of Images"
              name="imageName"
            ></input>
            <label id="labelSix">Lead Actor Names</label>
            <input
              onChange={onChangeActor}
              id="inputSix"
              type="text"
              maxLength="500"
              placeholder="Name of Actor"
              name="actorName"
            ></input>
            <label id="labelSeven">Rating</label>
            <input
              onChange={onChangeRating}
              id="inputSeven"
              type="text"
              maxLength="10"
              placeholder="Rating"
              name="movieRating"
            ></input>
            <button onClick={transferValue} id="submitButton">
              Submit
            </button>
            <button id="removeButton" onClick={ondeleteHandler} >Remove Movie</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddMember;
```

My Member.js Code

```
import '../src/css/movie.css'

function Members({ data, onChangeHandler }) {
   
  const tableRows = (data) =>
    data.map((info, num) => {
      return (
        <tr key={info.id}  >
          <td>{info.id}</td>
          <td>{info.name}</td>
          <td>
            <img src={info["picture of image"]} alt=""></img>
          </td>
          <td>{info["lead actor"]}</td>
          <td>{info.rating}</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" onChange={()=>onChangeHandler(num)} ></input></td>
        </tr>
      );
    });

  return ( 
    <div>
      <table className="table table-stripped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Actors</th>
            <th>Rating</th>
            <th>Remove Items</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{tableRows(data)}</tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Members;
```

Can anyone help me to solve it.How come the I pass <input type="checkbox" onChange={()=>onChangeHandler(num)} > show on the ondeleteHandler function?

Comment: I have solve the errors but Can anyone tell me how come I cannot pass value num from <input type="checkbox" onChange={()=>onChangeHandler(num)} > so that it will shown on ondeleteHandler function?

Comment: how I am going to check the checkbox is checked or not checked by using onChange() ?

Answer (score 0):

The `checkEvent` function needs two arguments and currently you're only passing in one. You should pass the `event` aswell when using an arrow function like this is does not automaticly pass the `event`.

```js
<td><input type="checkbox" onChange={(e)=>onChangeHandler(e, num)} ></input></td>
```

Comment: How many I going to use onChange to checked whether the checkbox is checked or not checked?

Comment: Are you not already doing that in your `checkEvent` function?

Comment: But I have errors. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'checked') My App.js Code

Comment: Thanks. I  Think the errors is caused by me not putting the events. Its soved thanks

Comment: Ah awesome, goodluck!